# SQL How to Get a Part of the Amount Out of Multiple Quarters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having some difficulties figuring out how to build a query that would take out an amount called "plan" out of the year's quarters. Let me explain the data I am working with.
[image]

Here we have `plan_nextYear_Total` which is a multiplication of `plan_nextYear_price` and `plan_nextYear_qty` the quarters (which are named `q#_nextYear`) are QUANTITIES for each quarter in the year. So if you want the total amount for quarters you'll have to multiply each `q#_nextYear` by `plan_nextYear_price`. But the problem I have is this is all the data I got to work with and I need to make a query that will essentially take the two months inputs (monthStart and monthEnd) and display the total sum for that month range. The problem comes when I want to get a sum from lets say January to May which will involve another quarter. I have written the SQL code for each quarter independently which looks something like this:

```
DECLARE @monthStart NUMERIC (20, 5), @monthEnd NUMERIC (20, 5), @quarterPart NUMERIC (20, 5)
SET @monthStart = 2
SET @monthEnd = 8;
SET @quarterPart = ((@monthEnd-@monthStart)+1)/3
SELECT plan_nextYear_Total, plan_nextYear_price, plan_nextYear_qty, q1_nextyear, q2_nextyear, q3_nextyear, q4_nextyear,
    CASE 
        --Base quarters
        WHEN @monthStart >= 1 AND @monthStart <= 3 AND @monthEnd <= 3 
            THEN (plan_nextYear_price * q1_nextyear) * @quarterPart

        WHEN @monthStart >= 4 AND @monthStart <= 6 AND @monthEnd <= 6 
            THEN (plan_nextYear_price * q2_nextyear) * @quarterPart

        WHEN @monthStart >= 7 AND @monthStart <=9 AND @monthEnd <= 9 
            THEN (plan_nextYear_price * q3_nextyear) * @quarterPart

        WHEN @monthStart >= 10 AND @monthStart <= 12 AND @monthEnd <= 12 
            THEN (plan_nextYear_price * q4_nextyear) * @quarterPart
    END AS 'RangedPlan'

FROM planning_sales_dynamic
```

This code utilizes a hard-coded number of months in `@quarterPart` variable because each quarter will have max up to 3 months anyways so for standalone quarters it is fine.
But lets say I want to select something from January to May (Or even from February to May) these are not whole quarters and I will have to figure out a way of obtaining the amount of months in each quarter to get accurate information. So how would I go about this? 
 
 I have made a query like this and it works, however it will assume that each of the 4 quarters are equal. And this is not always the case as seen in the data screenshot.

```
        --q1 + q2
        WHEN @monthStart >= 1 AND @monthStart <= 3 AND @monthEnd <= 6 
            THEN ((plan_nextYear_price * q1_nextyear) + (plan_nextYear_price * q2_nextyear)) * ((@monthEnd-@monthStart)+1)/6
```

Unfortunately there is no data for each individual month, otherwise it would not be an issue. Any points would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please do not use imagines for data, use tabular text

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish - please show a [mre] with emphasis on minimum, including sample data and desired results which clear logic on how the results are derived.

Comment: You say it would not be an issue if there were data for each individual month. So just use a CTE or nested query to calculate 12 monthly values as individual columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SET @monthStart = 2
SET @monthEnd = 8;
SELECT plan_nextYear_Total, plan_nextYear_price, plan_nextYear_qty, q1_nextyear, q2_nextyear, q3_nextyear, q4_nextyear,
    (
          CASE WHEN  1 BETWEEN @monthStart AND @monthEnd THEN q1_nextyear ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN  2 BETWEEN @monthStart AND @monthEnd THEN q1_nextyear ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN  3 BETWEEN @monthStart AND @monthEnd THEN q1_nextyear ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN  4 BETWEEN @monthStart AND @monthEnd THEN q2_nextyear ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN  5 BETWEEN @monthStart AND @monthEnd THEN q2_nextyear ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN  6 BETWEEN @monthStart AND @monthEnd THEN q2_nextyear ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN  7 BETWEEN @monthStart AND @monthEnd THEN q3_nextyear ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN  8 BETWEEN @monthStart AND @monthEnd THEN q3_nextyear ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN  9 BETWEEN @monthStart AND @monthEnd THEN q3_nextyear ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN 10 BETWEEN @monthStart AND @monthEnd THEN q4_nextyear ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN 11 BETWEEN @monthStart AND @monthEnd THEN q4_nextyear ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN 12 BETWEEN @monthStart AND @monthEnd THEN q4_nextyear ELSE 0 END
    ) * plan_nextYear_price / 3 AS RangedPlan
FROM planning_sales_dynamic
```

This selectively includes each quarter quantity between 0 and 3 times based on number of months included. It then applies price and divides by 3 to account for months vs quarters.

For @monthStart = 2 and @monthEnd = 8, it will include two-thirds of Q1, all of Q2, two-thirds of Q3, and none of Q4.